# exception in file reading

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, file-handling

I am having an exception in this code and I am unable to figure out the problem.
This code runs without while loop but with the WHILE loop it gives exception

```
 ProbabilityQueryTutorial.main(ProbabilityQueryTutorial.java:47)
```

Comment: I can't figure out what is wrong is **not** an accepted form of a question here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `NullPointerException`  gets thrown in this line:

```
at ProbabilityQueryTutorial.main(ProbabilityQueryTutorial.java:47)
```

I am not sure which line it is, exactly (maybe you can point it out?). But I noticed a few other things that might get into your way:

**variable names**

your variable names are with capital letters. That's generally discouraged, because only `class` names should have capital letters. Example:

```
String File="C:\\testing.txt";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(File));
```

`File` is a Java class for a *file* object but you are using it as a string.

**readLine()**

```
sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) !=null)
```

in the while condition you are already assigning the return value of `br.readLine()` to the variable `sCurrentLine`. But you also do the same *before* entering the while loop. Meaning, if you *want* to skip the first line of the file, that's ok. But if you need the first line, you should delete the assignment before the while loop and just keep the while as it is.

**null instantiation**

When you don't need the variables outside the `while`loop (e.g. the variable `String sCurrentLine`) then there is no need for you to declare it *before* the while-loop and instantiate it with `null`. Just move it inside the while and declare it when you need it the first time. (That way you avoid having `null` variables laying around).

Now if you are still having the error, maybe we can narrow the search down a little further. Just tell us in which line the exception gets thrown.

Comment: thankyou for replying :) the error is in like
bn.getEvidenceController().setObservations( evidence ); 

oky i am changing the names of variables